Multiple execution of fetch
I have built a javascript function to create a project (= picture + title + category)
using an API using fetch. After the response of the API, I modify DOM to display the new list of projects.
Initially, the fetch was going well but now it is executed multiple time without any request.
The first project is created properly (once) but as soon as I create a second project, it is sent twice (2 projects created). If I create an other project after, it is created 3 ou 4 time. Then the next project will be created 6 or 7 time, etc...
I don't know how to avoid multiple creation of project via fetch.
// ******************************* FONCTION ENREGISTREMENT DU NOUVEAU PROJET *************************************
let errorMessage = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
async function enregistrerProjet(imageInput, titleInput, categoryInput) {
    // Création de l'objet FormData
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", imageInput);
    formData.append("title", titleInput);
    formData.append("category", categoryInput);

    try {
        // Envoi du projet via API /works   
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5678/api/works", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + tokenLogin,
            },
            body: formData,
        })
        const responseProjet = await response.json();
        
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'ajout d'un élément (${response.status}). Veuillez réessayer plus tard.`)
        }
        projets.push(responseProjet); // ajout du nouveau projet au tableau projets

        // Récupération de l'élément du DOM qui accueillera la galerie
        const divGallery = document.querySelector(".gallery");
        // Création d’une balise dédiée au nouveau projet
        const idProjet = document.createElement("figure");
        idProjet.id = "portfolioFigure_" + responseProjet.id;
        idProjet.dataset.idCategorie = responseProjet.categoryId;
        // Création des balises 
        const imageProjet = document.createElement("img");
        imageProjet.src = responseProjet.imageUrl;
        imageProjet.alt = responseProjet.title;
        const titreProjet = document.createElement("figcaption");
        titreProjet.innerText = responseProjet.title;
        // Rattachement de la balise projet à la division Gallery
        divGallery.appendChild(idProjet);
        idProjet.appendChild(imageProjet);
        idProjet.appendChild(titreProjet);
        // ajout d'une balise image pour affichage projet
        idProjet.classList.add("image");
        document.getElementById("modifyProject").className = "modal-masque"; // masquage de la modale
        document.getElementById("galeriePhoto").className = "modal-wrapper"; // réinitialisation de la div galeriePhoto
        masquerModaleAjoutphoto(); // Masquer la modale 2 (Ajout photo)
        // Regénération de la galerie des projets
        document.querySelector(".gallery").innerHTML = "";
        genererProjets(projets);

    } catch (error) {
            errorMessage.textContent = "Erreur d'envoi du projet."; // vérifier le code erreur *************************
            // Attendre un appui clavier
            document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                errorMessage.textContent = ""; // Une touche est pressée, efface le message
            });
            // Attendre un clic de souris
            document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                errorMessage.textContent = ""; // Un click est détecté, efface le message
            });
            alert(error);
    };

};

Here the code I use enregistrerProjet function (it is the function verifierboutonValider):
// ********************** FONCTION ACTIVATION/DESACTIVATION DU BOUTON DE VALIDATION (nouveau projet) ****************************
function verifierboutonValider() {
    const boutonValidationprojet = document.getElementById("boutonValidprojet");
    if (validPhoto && validTitre && validCategorie) {
        boutonValidationprojet.className = "btn-on_2"; // activer le bouton
        // Ajout d'un écouter appui bouton "Valider"
        document.getElementById("formulaire").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            enregistrerProjet(imageInput, titleInput, categoryInput);
        }, { once: true });
    } else {
        boutonValidationprojet.className = "btn-off_2"; // désactiver le bouton
    };
};


I have just changed the function verifierboutonValider (the function that use the genererProjet function), adding a removeEventListener. So I should be sure I do not call my function genererProjet twice). But it didn't change the problem. Project is created twice via fetch...
Below the new code of the function verifierboutonValider:
// ********************** FONCTION ACTIVATION/DESACTIVATION DU BOUTON DE VALIDATION (nouveau projet) ****************************
function verifierboutonValider() {
    const boutonValidationprojet = document.getElementById("boutonValidprojet");
    // Suppression de l'écouteur appui bouton "Valider" (au cas où il aurait déjà été créé)
    document.getElementById("formulaire").removeEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        enregistrerProjet(imageInput, titleInput, categoryInput);
    }, { once: true });
    if (validPhoto && validTitre && validCategorie) {
        boutonValidationprojet.className = "btn-on_2"; // activer le bouton
        // Ajout d'un écouteur appui bouton "Valider"
        document.getElementById("formulaire").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            enregistrerProjet(imageInput, titleInput, categoryInput);
        }, { once: true });
    } else {
        boutonValidationprojet.className = "btn-off_2"; // désactiver le bouton
    };
};


Can you share the code where you use enregistrerProjet

Your mistake is not in this function, it is in the way you are using it, and that code is missing here.

at a guess, probably adding some event listener multiple times to something

You also need to move the click event handlers outside the functions. Please delegate to the nearest static container as possible

Could you explain more : "You also need to move the click event handlers outside the functions. Please delegate to the nearest static container as possible"
